# Swift error: cannot convert value of type 'B -> (A) -> ()' to expected argument type '(A) -> Void'

Tags: swift, syntax

I have a Swift program that produces a compiler error I cannot understand. It boils down to the following code fragment.

Class `A`is a helper class that is upon initialization provided with a handler function that is to be called later. This function has an `A` object as an argument.

Class `B` initializes an object of type `A` and has a function `f` that should be used as the handler. Alternatively, an anonymous code block (closure) could be provided.

```
class A {
    init(_: (A) -> Void) {}
}

class B {
    let a = A(f)
    func f(a: A) {}
}
```

This produces the following compiler message:

```
error: cannot convert value of type 'B -> (A) -> ()' to expected argument type '(A) -> Void'
let a = A(f)
          ^
```

`Void` and `()` are equivalent, I suppose.

I do not even understand the type expression with the double `->`. What kind of type is this?

Can anyone explain what's wrong here? And, how to do it right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't refer to an instance method (like `f`) while initializing an instance property (like `a`), because the instance is exactly what we are in the middle of creating. One solution is to declare your instance property `lazy`, like this:

```
class A {
    init(_: (A) -> Void) {}
}

class B {
    func f(a: A) {}
    lazy var a : A = A(self.f)
}
```

That is legal because `lazy` guarantees that the initializer for `a` won't be evaluated until *later*, when the instance *has* been created. Note that `self` is absolutely required in this context (and in general I recommend you always use it wherever it can be used).

Another solution is to declare `a` as an `A!` (so that it has an initial value, namely `nil`) and initialize it "for real" later. For example:

```
class A {
    init(_: (A) -> Void) {}
}

class B {
    func f(a: A) {}
    var a : A!
    init() {
        self.a = A(self.f)
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for pointing me the right direction. Please see my answer as I have some remarks I cannot make in a comment :-)

Comment: If my answer helped you please consider accepting it.

Comment: Yes, of course. I'd still like to know what the type expression `B -> (A) -> ()` and the error message are actually meaning. :-)

Comment: `B -> (A) -> ()` is the type of your `func f`. This is because in Swift, an instance method is a curried class method.

Answer (score 0):

@matt pointed me the right direction — thank you very much. His solution is the `a1` variant here:

```
class B {
    func f(a: A) {}
    lazy var a1 : A = A(self.f)       // ok
    lazy var a2 : A = A(f)            // error
    lazy var a3     = A(self.f)       // error
    lazy var a4     = A(f)            // error
}
```

Interestingly, all other variants `a2`, `a3`, `a4` do *not* work. `a2` and `a4` produce the original *"cannot convert value"* error, `a3` says *"use of unresolved identifier 'self'"*.

The disadvantage of the `lazy` solution is that `a` is now a `var` instead of a constant. I have found an alternative way by assigning the constant value during initialization:

```
class B {
    let a: A
    init() {
        a = A() { (A) -> Void in … }  // ok
    }
}
```

Interestingly, this *only* works with a closure. The code

```
class B {
    let a: A
    init() {
        a = A(f)                      // error
    }
    func f(a: A) { … }
}
```

gives the compiler error *"use of 'self' in method call 'f' before all stored properties are initialized"*.

Nevertheless, even in the closure variant, `self` cannot be used since it is not yet fully initialized.

Comment: Right, but you are now answering a different question. Your original question _assumes_ that there _is_ an instance method `f` to which we wish to refer. Naturally if there is no such method the whole problem goes away. :))))

Comment: "Interestingly, this only works with a closure." Not true (if by "closure" your mean "anonymous function"). It would work just fine if `f` was a _local_ function _inside the `init`_. The problem, as I keep trying to explain to you, is when it is an instance method.

Comment: Yes, I believe I understand the underlying "mechanics". As long as the object is not fully initialized, `self`is not accessible, obviously. Even if that is done inside a function/closure that will be called much later when the object has actually been initialized long ago (or is never called at all).
The reason for this was a location-managing class (`A`) that calls `reverseGeocodeLocation` with a completion handler. Class `B` uses that location manager and shall be notified as soon as the result is available.
Maybe the whole approach is not optimal and I should use delegates instead.

Comment: Actually I love the idea of using a completion handler when you've got asynchronous code and need to call back to the caller later. So stick with this, is my advice. — But I remind you, my answer was not about that, because that is not what you asked. My answer explains _the compiler error message_ that you got, i.e what was wrong with your code.

Comment: I agree. Delegates always mean a tighter coupling as the service-providing class has to know about the service-using class, which is usually done with a protocol. On the other hand, the delegate strategy means a less tight coupling in terms of initialization dependencies, as we can see here.